# React Native Searchable Dropdown: Text remains Invisible

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using [react-native-searchable-dropdown](https://github.com/zubairpaizer/react-native-searchable-dropdown) to search a list of data and select them. This is the [working example](https://snack.expo.io/SkpOHlOGU) that I am following.

> However, when I use a different API URL, I am facing the following
>   problems:
>
> 1. The item itself remains invisible
> 2. Trying to search the item shows error
>
> [This is my code with different API URL](https://snack.expo.io/Bkx7ox!MI). On another one of my project, using `setSort` property helped solved the searching issue but in this example, it's showing error.

It would be really helpful if anyone with previous experience regarding this issue can help solve it. Thank you.

**Here's the code snippet from my code:**

```
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            //Successful response from the API Call
            this.setState({
              serverData: [...this.state.serverData, ...responseJson.movies],
              //adding the new data in Data Source of the SearchableDropdown
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 30 }}>
            <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
              Searchable Dropdown from Dynamic Array from Server
            </Text>
            <SearchableDropdown
              setSort={(item, searchedText)=> item.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchedText.toLowerCase())}
              onTextChange={text => console.log(text)}
              //On text change listner on the searchable input
              onItemSelect={item => alert(JSON.stringify(item))}
              //onItemSelect called after the selection from the dropdown
              containerStyle={{ padding: 5 }}
              //suggestion container style
              textInputStyle={{
                //inserted text style
                padding: 12,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#ccc',
                backgroundColor: '#FAF7F6',
              }}
              itemStyle={{
                //single dropdown item style
                padding: 10,
                marginTop: 2,
                backgroundColor: '#FAF9F8',
                borderColor: '#bbb',
                borderWidth: 1,
              }}
              itemTextStyle={{
                //single dropdown item's text style
                color: '#222',
              }}
              itemsContainerStyle={{
                //items container style you can pass maxHeight
                //to restrict the items dropdown hieght
                maxHeight: '50%',
              }}
              items={this.state.serverData}
              //mapping of item array
              defaultIndex={2}
              //default selected item index
              placeholder="placeholder"
              //place holder for the search input
              resetValue={false}
              //reset textInput Value with true and false state
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              //To remove the underline from the android input
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This workaround requires the module to be modified. The `setSort` function allows you to correct errors for the search. However, you cannot see the name in the search list. By default, the value of the key in the name must be `'name'`.

The reason can be found where the list is returned.

**index.js in react-native-searchable-dropdown**

```js
renderItems = (item, index) => {
....
            <View style={{ flex: 0.9, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
              <Text>{ item.name }</Text>  <== The value of the list key is name.
            </View>
....
```

If you want to solve the problem right now, the key value of the API must be changed

```
{
  "title": "The Basics - Networking",
  "description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
  "movies": [
    { "id": "1", "name": "Star Wars", "releaseYear": "1977" },
    { "id": "2", "name": "Back to the Future", "releaseYear": "1985" },
    { "id": "3", "name": "The Matrix", "releaseYear": "1999" },
    { "id": "4", "name": "Inception", "releaseYear": "2010" },
    { "id": "5", "name": "Interstellar", "releaseYear": "2014" }
  ]
}
```

You can also convert your search by adding a movie genre.

```
{
  "title": "The Basics - Networking",
  "description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
  "movies": [
    { "id": "1", "genre": "Fantasy", "name": "Star Wars", "releaseYear": "1977" },
    { "id": "2", "genre": "Fantasy", "name": "Back to the Future", "releaseYear": "1985" },
    { "id": "3", "genre": "Action", "name": "The Matrix", "releaseYear": "1999" },
    { "id": "4", "genre": "Future", "name": "Inception", "releaseYear": "2010" },
    { "id": "5", "genre": "Future", "name": "Interstellar", "releaseYear": "2014" }
  ]
}
```

**And You can use `setSort` function**

```js
setSort={(item, searchedText)=> item.genre.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchedText.toLowerCase())}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. However, in my original project, the invisible item issue still remains. For clarification here's my [api call](https://prnt.sc/qxt9qj) and my [list of data](https://prnt.sc/qxtab2). My **setsort** is like this `setSort={(item, searchedText) => item.freelancer_name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchedText.toLowerCase())}`. I can search and select `freelancer_name` without issue BUT it remains invisible.

Comment: Here is some screenshot from the app: [search](https://prnt.sc/qxthki) and [select](https://prnt.sc/qxthqw)

Comment: @BeepBoop You don't seem to know much about json's concept yet. If you look at the json value in my answer, there is a 'name' in the value of the key. But you don't have a name.

Comment: So I will need to change `freelancer_name` to `name` and ONLY THEN I will be able to view my list of items? If that's the only workaround then I guess I will need to look for other libraries since I am calling my API multiple times on multiple files. Also, I have other KEYs such `master_name`, `username` etc., and if I were to change those to `name`, it will cause confusion in the future. Thanks though.

Comment: Also, is there anyway I can change the KEY name from React Native instead of changing it on the backend?

Comment: @BeepBoop  It's not possible at the moment. If you have a duplicate name key in one table, you may want to look for another module. If my answer was helpful, please vote for and choose my answer and close the question.