# React Native Searchable Dropdown: Invisible Text List

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using [react-native-searchable-dropdown](https://github.com/zubairpaizer/react-native-searchable-dropdown) to search a list of data and select them. This is the [working example](https://snack.expo.io/SkpOHlOGU) that I am following.

> However, when I use a different API URL, I am facing the following
>   problem:
>
> 1. The item itself remains invisible
>
> I can Search and Select the item, and it also loads the API result but the only issue is that the **Text List** remains invisible.

I received a suggestion on my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60071776/react-native-searchable-dropdown-text-remains-invisible) but it felt cumbersome. So I am looking for better alternatives.

*It would be really helpful if anyone with previous experience regarding this issue can help solve it.*

**Here's the code snippet from my project:**

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            //test search dropdown picker
            serverData: [],
            //test search dropdown picker
        }
    }

componentDidMount() {
    this.apiFreelancerList();
}

apiFreelancerList() {
    let self = this;
    AsyncStorage.getItem('my_token').then((keyValue) => {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: Constants.API_URL + 'user_m/freelancer_list/',
            responseType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'X-API-KEY': Constants.API_KEY,
                'Authorization': keyValue,
            },
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('mTopUp Response Data: ', response.data.data);
                self.setState({
                    serverData: response.data.data,
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('mTopUp Error: ', error) //Display error
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {
                <View>
                    <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
                        Name
                    </Text>
                    <SearchableDropdown
                        onTextChange={text => console.log(text)}

                        onItemSelect={item => alert(JSON.stringify(item))}

                        containerStyle={{ padding: 5 }}

                        textInputStyle={{
                            padding: 12,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: '#ccc',
                            backgroundColor: '#FAF7F6',
                        }}

                        itemStyle={{
                            padding: 10,
                            marginTop: 2,
                            backgroundColor: '#FAF9F8',
                            borderColor: '#bbb',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                        }}

                        itemTextStyle={{
                            color: '#222',
                        }}

                        itemsContainerStyle={{
                            maxHeight: '50%',
                        }}

                        items={this.state.serverData}

                        defaultIndex={2}

                        placeholder="Please Select Name"

                        resetValue={false}

                        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"

                        setSort={(item, searchedText) => item.freelancer_name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchedText.toLowerCase())}
                    />
                </View>
            }
        </View>
    );
};
```

From the above code I am trying to get `freelancer_name` from this [List of Data](https://prnt.sc/qxtab2).

**Here are the screenshot from my app:**

1. Screenshot for [Searching](https://prnt.sc/qxthki)
2. Screenshot for [Selecting](https://prnt.sc/qxthqw)

Answer (score 0):

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('my_token').then((keyValue) => {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: Constants.API_URL + 'user_m/freelancer_list/',
            responseType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'X-API-KEY': Constants.API_KEY,
                'Authorization': keyValue,
            },
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('mTopUp Response Data: ', response.data.data);
                this.setState({    //<--change self to this
                    serverData: response.data.data,
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('mTopUp Error: ', error) //Display error
    });
```

Please replace this code and try.

Comment: Adding `this` causes TypeError. The problem is related with `react-native-searchable-dropdown`. This was my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60071776/react-native-searchable-dropdown-text-remains-invisible) regarding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are sending a Async call to fetch data from API and showing it to display in Flat-list or searchable-list (Flat-list requires data in state to show or display before rendering  otherwise show empty and not render again). No-doubt, ComponentDidMount method called very first on screen load but you render method did not wait for it and your state is empty (you may check it by putting a break point on it), due to this your searchable list displaying empty.

**Solution** you call your method

> AsyncStorage.getItem

in any previous screen or js file where you have ComponentDidMount method, and put this data to global variable and use this variable in   your state variable for example

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      serverData: global.DataPreScreen, //Data Source for the SearchableDropdown
    };
  }
```

then you don't have need to call this method on this screen.
Moreover, in your given example, data is hard-coded and initialize instantly while  you are sending a Asycn call in which next process or instructions automatically executed instead of waiting the response of call. Furthermore, you should always used two **.then** statement because one actually tells about HTTP response (success or failure) and other gives you ,your desire data if HTTP response is OK (200 OK).
If you don't understand my explanation, please let me know then I'll give you a proper example, which may help you to find your solution.

Comment: @vijay kahar. this error happen when you have no data in your state variable but its rendering in your flat-list (this happen due to empty rendering, if you pass hard-coded data or dynamic data. This will no longer exist and your flat-list will work fine). Please put a break point flat-list and check data on console (you state variable may empty, I have safe problem during my learning process). Let me know if you don't understand.

Comment: Please do provide an example.